# How to track how many request sent to web services or API by users?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, google-analytics

How many requests have been sent or how many times any user has requested data from particular web service? I want to track the count the records like as google analytics.

suppose I have created a web service like as follow.

```
function myWebServices() {
  $data = array();
  $data['usersInfo'] = 'lorem Ipsum';
  $data['status'] = '1';
  return json_encode($data);
}
```

I have sent URL of this web service to my vendors, they access this function and get the data. But I also want to track the vendor's request, how many times they have sent.

Is there is any way to track this like as google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event via an HTTP request each time you receive an incoming API request.

The URL would be something like this:

https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&cid=[SOME-USER-ID]&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=[EVENT-CATEGORY]&ea=[EVENT-ACTION]&cs=[EVENT-SOURCE]

Mind that [SOME-USER-ID] param is required. You can read further on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

Comment: Can I put any random string for `cid`.  Second thing is how many parameters are required in above url.

Comment: @Nitin for cid you can use `$results = $this->getResults($analytics, $profile);
  
  $table_id = $results->profileInfo->tableId;`  and then `cid=$table_id`

Comment: @Nitin, the cid id what identifies a user (client id), so if you want to track recurring visits (recurring uses of you web service) this should be unique per user. Not special format is required - Google suggests the uuid to avoid collisions, but any unique id will do. Required parameters are tid (account id), cid (client id) v (version), t (hit type) and (for hit type even the category and action. The cs parameter is actually campaign source and is not required. Optional are el for label (string) and ev (value, int).

Comment: If your API is used by multiple third-party services, I'd suggest to send their  ID as cid to be able to group by them. But generally you can send any random (or rather fixed) value.